# Process name + Window Title + Suspend Selected Process

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a software that is going to check for multiple processes from the same name and then suspend the selected one. For example: app1

The user will open e.g 10x the "app1.exe" application Each application will have a different window title.

The software will list the 10 process names with their respective window titles. What I want is, how to suspend the selected item from Combobox? I'm using a structure to suspend a process (Freeze):

SuspendProcess(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)

But he will read the "Window Title Name Example - app1", and I just want that the combobox read the "app1" from the selected combobox item.

It's possible to do this?

Comment: New User + First Question = Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is get the processes by calling the [Process.GetProcessByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.110).aspx) method, bind the results to your ComboBox, and set the [DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your ComboBox to the Process' [ProcessName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname(v=vs.110).aspx). That away whenever the user wants to suspend the process, you can get the [SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) (which would be the process) and then you can pass the respective process to your SuspendProcess method.

Here is a quick example (free-typed, watch for my typos) demonstrating just that:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  With ComboBox1
    .DataSource = Process.GetProcessByName("application name here.exe")
    .DisplayMember = "ProcessName"
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
  SuspendProcess(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```